# How do I set editable property of rating bar to false

Tags: android

How should I set the editable property of **rating bar** to `false`?
I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
holder.rb=(RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
holder.rb.setActivated(false);
```

Comment: You mean to activate and deactive ? `holder.rb.setEnable(false)`

Answer (score 5):

To disactivate view use :

```
holder.rb=(RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1); 
holder.rb.setEnable(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

try this in your xml : `android:isIndicator="true"`

or this in java : `holder.rb.setIsIndicator(true);`

I guess you want your rating bar be unchangeable by user. If yes use the code i've mentioned above.
But if you just want to enable or disable your rating bar you can use this line:

```
holder.rb.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: thanks you for helping me .iam a beginner in android

Answer (score 3):

Try `holder.rb.setEnabled(false);` or `holder.rb.setIsIndicator(true);` instead.
both of them will work.

Answer (score 1):

just add android:isIndicator="true" in your xml! thats it!